# Python: On error in thread, how do I restart program from the beginning

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to python and error handling. I am running a program that connects to a data source and continuously receives market data, every so often I encounter an "Exception in thread Thread" which I think happens because an issue with the data connection occurs, so the computation that the program should be doing can't be completed. I think I can resolve this problem by restarting the program from the beginning if the connection fails. Something like... if this type of error is encountered, go back to the beginning and try to reconnect, and if that doesn't fix the problem after a few attempts, stop trying. The thread is currently started in the App class, when the class is initialized, so going back to the first line would solve the problem, I'm just not sure how I would do this. My main code is fairly complex, but is structured like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
      my_app = App(args)

while my_app.market_open():
      do some computation
      do some more computation, etc. 

my_app.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function `def main():`
and within it, do the (re)connection stuff.

Then you write the famous

```
if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    main()
```

To restart from anywhere within your program, call `main()` from wherever you are! In this case, you put everything under/after `if __name__ == "__main__"` into `main()`s definition and from inside `main()` call `main()`

Comment: Can I put all the code inside main() and then in if __name__ == '__main__':  put while True: try: main() except: continue? Or would it be better to call main again from inside main?

Comment: I would say to call main again from inside `main()` - so that the program begins from start - `if <condition>:` is fulfilled (tested inside `main()`)

Comment: You have to imagine: if you call `main()` from inside `main()` it is like a `goto` to the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: @КатАмаri welcome! Happy to have been helpful! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might also try putting your calculations into a try / except loop to catch the error and redirect the code to a new function call? You will need to specify the error:

```
try:
    while my_app.market_open():
        do some computation
        do some more computation, etc.

except WhatEverYourErrorIsHere:
    while my_app.market_open():
        do some computation again?
```

Here is example running different functions in two threads every minute. Again, you will need to specify the Error to catch:

```
import schedule, threading, datetime
def someCallableFunction():
    try:
        print('running someCallableFunction\n')
    except ConnectionError:
        print(datetime.utcnow(), 'External Connection Error')
        return
def someOtherCallableFunction():
    try:
        print('running someOtherCallableFunction\n')
    except ConnectionError:
        print(datetime.utcnow(), 'External Connection Error')
        return
def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

schedule.every(1).minutes.at(':00').do(run_threaded, someCallableFunction)   
schedule.every(1).minutes.at(':00').do(run_threaded,
    someOtherCallableFunction)   

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: I will try this also, would you know how I would refer to an Exception in a thread specifically?

Comment: Small example of code added above. If you dont have schedule, then pip install schedule...

Comment: Thank you for the example that is helpful